# Getting data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 table one called semester(ID,name, academic_year) and the other working_semester(ID, Working_semester_ID)
The working_semester_ID is the same as ID from semester.
[data for semester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSEZe.png)
[data for working_semster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJTZ.png)

How can i get the next working semester by joining them and using he academic_year column

Comment: With a join. For a more detailed answer provide more detail in your question

Answer (score 0):

You mean to simple join?

```
select *,s. from semester As S 
join working_semester As W on s.ID = W. Working_semester_ID
```

Comment: Ok thanks 
But do you know how i can get the data where i reference the data in the working_semester and get the next date using the academic_year ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need?

Comment: Like the current data in the working_semester data is ID = 1 and working_semester_id  = 36 which in the semester table would be Jan 2016. So i need to join them such that i would get the data that is after the Jan 2016 which would be Jun 2016 using the academic_year column.
But no matter what i say it always return the jan 2016

Comment: Your semester table only has semesters market January [year], from where do you want the query to pick up July? Do you want to get the next semester from your table, or do you just want to add six months to whatever the semester start date is?

Comment: to get the next semester from the table